# Safari makes navigation bar to jump when hovering elements, this works ok on other browsers

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to make this navigation bar to work without that "jumpy" effect on Safari.
It works ok on all other browsers.
The problem is that hovering on the links make the bar jumps down.

You can check the code here
http://jsfiddle.net/kpady8hr/14/

```
<nav class="top-menu">
<div class="divider first"></div>             
    <a href="#" class="product">
        <span class="hover">Link1</span>
        <span class="link">Link1</span>
    </a>                   
<div class="divider"></div>              
    <a href="#" class="product">
        <span class="hover">Link2</span>
        <span class="link">Link2</span>
    </a>                    
<div class="divider"></div>         
    <a href="#" class="product">
        <span class="hover">Link3</span>
        <span class="link">Link3</span>
    </a>
<div class="divider last"></div>
</nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So what is the issue on Safari? You need to explain clearly in your question

Comment: Sorry, I just added that the problem is that the bar jumps down when hovering on the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style the links with vertical-align and compensate in the divider.
For example:

```
.top-menu .divider.first {
  background-position: left center; /* change this */
}

.top-menu .product {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thierry! I added your css suggestion and then the only thing missing was adding background-position: center to the other .divider elements.
Thanks a lot!